# Ajax and VbScript: fetching Post variable in test.asp

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, vbscript, asp-classic

current i am trying to use ajax for my site ....... because of size of data is not limited i need to use post method for send data to database but the problem is i am unable to fetch the Post variables in the test.asp

here is the script i am using

```
function SaveData(content ) 
{
    var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    msg=xmlhttp.responseText;
    alert(msg);
    }
  }

 var para = encodeURIComponent("content="+content)
xmlhttp.open("POST","test.asp",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
xmlhttp.send(para)

}
```

and here is test.asp code

```
t = Request.form("content")
Response.write(t)
```

please help me solving this problem of fetching the Post method variable in test.asp

if possible any one  can share code of jquery ajax with post method in asp classic too that would also be helpful

Comment: have you tried just encoding the value of `content`? ie `var para = "content=" + encodeURIComponent(content);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
var para = encodeURIComponent("content="+content)
```

into this:

```
var para = "content=" + encodeURIComponent(content);
```

The way that it was, you were submitting something like this to the server:

```
content%3Dtest%20data%20123
```

With the adjusted line of code, you're submitting something like this, which is as it should be:

```
content=test%20data%20123
```

Have you considered using a JavaScript library such as [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/)? A library will [abstract away](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) all this unpleasantness:

```
$.post("test.asp", { 'content': content }, function(data) {
    alert("Returned data: " + data);
});
```

Comment: also edited the mistake in the post  
thanks for indicating that mistake

Comment: @NewbieFreak: I updated my answer with another problem I found.

Comment: thanks alot i have tested your solution and it would like a charm ... :D thanks alot

Comment: No problem! I noticed you asked for a jQuery snippet in your original question, so I added it, if you need it.